# My centOS 7 minimal font screwed up when trying to tail modsecurity audit log

Tags: nginx, centos, mod-security

My font display was completely normal. But right after i cat or tail /var/log/modsec_audit.log, my font becomes like this. Any solution?

Image link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkIyj.png

Answer (score 1):

execute the command `reset` in your console.
if this doesn't do the trick:

- press: `CTRL+J`
- type: `reset`
- press `CTRL+J` again

Comment: Problem solved :D ty sir